# iPhone SDK: How to normalize audio playback using AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios4, core-audio, avaudioplayer, avfoundation

I'm doing some testing with AVAudioPlayer and notice that the audio is very low. Some apps, like Audio Memos Free, has an option to "auto normalize" playback volume and this results in a significantly louder playback than if I have the AVAudioPlayer volume set to 100%. How are apps like that normalizing playback volume? I don't see any control over the in the AVFoundation classes.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to normalise the audio?

Answer (score -1):

In AVAudioSession class there are various categories to handle playback http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html. In this if you use AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback you will get higher playback sound compared to other categories like AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord. Also there is a setVolume: property for AVAudioPlayer.
If you need more control over your audio you can use Core Audio framework. Please refer http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreAudioReference/CoreAudioTypes/CompositePage.html  and the sample Speak Here application http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html for more details. Hope this helps you.